# Common points of two measurable functions

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, measurable-sets

Let $(X,\Omega,\mu)$ be a measure space($\Omega$ is the $\sigma-$algebra and $\mu$ is the measure).
Let $(Y,T)$ be a topological space.
A function $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is called measurable iff for every $O \in T$
$$ f^{-1} (O) \in \Omega $$

If $f$ and $g$ are two measurable functions, then is the set $E = \{ x \in X : f(x) = g(x) \}$ measurable ?

I have found counterexamples showing that it does not hold in case of general topological spaces. What I wish to know is what happens when $Y$ is a general metric space ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No good if $Y$ is a metric space and $T$ is an arbitrary $\sigma$-algebra on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saying $Y$ is a metric space and $T$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets on $T$ ... that is not enough.

**Counterexample.**
Let $Y$ be a set with cardinal $|Y| > \mathfrak c$, where $\mathfrak c = 2^{\aleph_0}$.  With the discrete metric, $d(y_1,y_2) = 1$ if $y_1 \ne y_2$, we get of course that $T = \mathcal P(Y)$, the power set of $Y$.

Consider the product $\sigma$-algebra $T \otimes T$ on the Cartesian product $Y \times Y$.  From $|Y| > \mathfrak c$ we can prove that $T \otimes T$ is not the power set of $Y \times Y$.  Indeed,  the "diagonal"
$$
\Delta = \{(y,y) : y \in Y\}
$$
is not an element of $T \otimes T$. (see [HERE](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/39882/product-of-borel-sigma-algebras) .)

For a measurable function $f,g : X \to Y$, define $h : X \to Y \times Y$ by
$h(x) = \big(f(x), g(x)\big)$.  Then
$$
\{x : f(x) = g(x) \} = h^{-1}\big(\Delta\big) .
$$
Now $\Delta \not\in T \otimes T$, so it could happen that
$\{x : f(x) = g(x) \} \not\in \Omega$ . The simplest way to get an example is to take $X = Y \times Y$ and
$\Omega = T \otimes T$ and $h$ the identity function on $Y \times Y$.  That is, $f\big((x_1, x_2)\big) = x_1$ and $g\big((x_1, x_2)\big) = x_2$.

---

To get the opposite answer, you could limit $Y$ to be a **separabale** metric space.
Another nice case is when $(X, \Omega, \mu)$ is a **complete** measure space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll have to understand the details, but I get the gist of the solution.

Comment: Also could you explain how did you come about this example?

Comment: I have known this "product sigma algebra in $Y \times Y$" counterexample for many years.  Anyone interested in abstract sigma-algebras would know it.  If I had to guess, maybe I learned it in Hewitt & Stromberg, *Real and Abstract Analysis*